# Booking form with conditional form action based on select option

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have this booking form below along with screenshot.

Since the hotel has 2 properties and 2 separate booking engines, I want it to be "form action=link-1.html" or "form action=link-2.html" depending on the selection from drop-down.

And the data i.e. Check-in, nights, and property should be sent to the booking engine.

To further clarify:

If Propery=Propery1 then form action=link-1.html; and 
If Propery=Propery2 then form action=link-2.html;

Please can anyone help me on this?

Thanks!

[image]

```
<form action="link-1.html" method="post" onSubmit="document.getElementById('CheckInDateParam').value=document.getElementById('textbox1').value;">
    <div class="row" style="margin-left:15px; margin-right:15px; margin-top:12px;">
        <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns">
            <label for="right-label" class="left">Check-In</label>
        </div>
        <div class="large-8 medium-8 columns">
            <input type="text" class="textField" id="textbox1" name="textbox1" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-left:15px; margin-right:15px;">
        <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns">
            <label for="right-label" class="left">Nights</label>
        </div>
        <div class="large-8 medium-8 columns">
            <select name="selStay" size="1" class="jumpMenuShort" id="selStay" onChange="document.getElementById('NumNightsparam').value=this.value; ">
                <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-left:15px; margin-right:15px;">
        <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns">
            <label for="right-label" class="left">Property</label>
        </div>
        <div class="large-8 medium-8 columns">
            <select name="selProperty" size="1" class="jumpMenuShort" id="property" onChange="document.getElementById('Propertyparam').value=this.value; ">
                <option value="" disabled selected>SELECT</option>
                <option value="2">SARJAPURA</option>
                <option value="2">MARATHAHALLI</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-left:15px; margin-right:15px;">
        <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns">
            <label for="right-label" class="left"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="large-8 medium-8 columns">
            <div class="booking-btn">
                <input type="hidden" name="CheckInDateParam" id="CheckInDateParam" />
                <input type="hidden" name="NumNightsparam" id="NumNightsparam" value="1" />
                <input type="image" src="images/bookNow.png" style="outline:none;" alt="Book Now" name="book now" width="91" height="25" border="0">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: https://jsbin.com/cuwakunahu/2/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Thanks Alexander. I'll check and get back at the earliest. Cheers!

Comment: Cool. The idea is to calculate the action each time the "property" changes: newActionLink = {'1': 'link-1.html', '2': 'link-2.html'}[$('#property').val()] and then set it to the forms "action" attribute. Just copied your code and made some minor modifications there.

Answer (score 1):

Add an eventListener for `input` or `change` on the target `<select>`, and alter the form's `action` property should do the work:

```js
var form = document.getElementById('tform');
var select = document.getElementById('test');

select.addEventListener('input', function() {
  var value = this.value;
  tform.action = value === '1' ? 'target1' : 'target2';
});
```

```html
<form id="tform" action="target1">
   <select id="test">
     <option value="1" selected>1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
   </select>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Hey thanks fuyushimoya... I'll check and get back to you at the earliest. Cheers!